# React Router redirecting href of CSS

Tags: react-router, href, relative-path

I have a my routes.js set up like this:

```
<Route path="users" component={requireAuth(users)} />
<Route path="user-:id" component={requireAuth(userSelect)} />
```

Everything works fine, my only problem arises when I change the dash to a forward slash:

```
<Route path="user/:id" component={requireAuth(userSelect)} />
```

When I do this, my css's href path changes, so when I open www.siteexample.com/user/1 I get a GET error like this:

```
GET http://siteexample.com/user/style/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<link href="style/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

It seems like when the forward slash is added, "user" becomes the root of the relative file path and react router tries to find the css files from there instead of the location of index.html. The link href should actually be

```
 http://siteexample.com/style/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Is there anything I can add to my href to force it to go to the main root of my site?

Comment: can you not link to your css file like href="/style/css/bootstrap.min.css"?

Comment: @nuway that did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link your CSS relative to the root of the site, like href="/style/css/bootstrap.min.css"